# css: setting text size to 20% bigger as known

Tags: html, css

I can set my `<p>` tags to a certain text size. But when It's set i want to be my `<h2>` to be 20% bigger.

Is this even possible? If yes, could you guys please help me a little bit on my way?

This is what i tried:

`h2, .h2 {
    font-size: @font_size + px * 25%;`

Thanks in advance.

Armando

Comment: In case you're using SASS (http://sass-lang.com/) , you could store the font-size in a variable ($h2-font-size: 18px;) and use it to adjust the font-size for example in a media query. font-size: $h2-font-size * 1.2;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use rem units for this.

The rem unit looks at the font size of the html or root element. So if you define your html unit size, you can scale your other font sizes based on that.

It looks like this:

```
html { font-size: 10px; }
body { font-size: 1.2rem; } /* 12 px */
h2   { font-size: 2rem; } /* 20px */
```

More information can be found here:

http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/font-size-with-rem

Keep in mind this is supported from IE9 and up:

http://caniuse.com/#search=rem